# How to join two graphs where each edge in the graph has a traversal cost associated to it

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

My question is similar to an existing one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1691013/how-does-one-join-two-graphs-in-graph-theory

But I'm specifically wondering what would be the new edge's costs, if the two graphs already have some traversal cost associated to them?

**Specification:** Construct a directed graph where the nodes are labeled. The edges of the graph are labeled with a traversal cost. They also obey the usual triangle inequality. That is, in a triangle such as the triangle inequality x + y ≥ z where x, y, and z are the costs associated with traversing these edges. The costs are real numbers may not exceed some specified cost interval. At a minimum, your library should be able to add edges to a graph, join two graphs that operate on the same cost interval and disjoint sets of nodes, and compute whether there is a path from one node to another and, if so, its cost.

I understood all the other requirements of the specification except for joining two graphs where the edges have traversal costs.

**My understanding:** While joining the two graphs, I should still maintain the triangle equality but the new edge cost will be a value in this range: [min cost that satisfies triangle in equality, cost interval].

I'm doing this project as for my practice and got the specification from an [internet source](http://homes.soic.indiana.edu/classes/fall2013/csci/p532-samth/assign01.html).

Comment if you like to know any more information.

Comment: Can the edges be of negative cost? Can you link the source of the task please?

Comment: How would having negative cost help here?
updated the source.